# Hybris PCM product category restriction

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

We are implementing Hybris PCM and we would like to create some product category restrictions.

Some employees should find only the products with a specific category. For example, some employees can see only products with category "drills," while other employees can see only products with category "shoes".

How can we do this in Backoffice and PCM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search restrictions (personalization) can be used to achieve this:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SearchRestriction;code[unique=true];active;generate;restrictedType(code);principal(uid);query
                               ;Product_restriction_1; true; false; Product; usergroup1; "{category} in ({{ select {pk} from {Category} where {code}='category1' }})"
                               ;Product_restriction_2; true; false; Product; usergroup2; "{category} in ({{ select {pk} from {Category} where {code}='category1' }})"
```

Here employees belonging to usergroup1 can see products  belonging to category1 and usergroup2 can see products belonging to category2 (these queries given above are just some dummy queries for quick understanding of concept).

Restriction type = product
Principal = user/ usergroup corresponding to the backoffice employee logging in

A more specific query to suit your requirement would be:

```
select {r.target} from { CategoryProductRelation as r join Category as c on {r.source}= {c.pk} } where {c.code}='shoes'
```

Hence please use an impex like:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SearchRestriction;code[unique=true];active;generate;restrictedType(code);principal(uid);query
                           ;Product_restriction_shoes; true; false; Product; shoeUser; " {pk} in ({{select {r.target} from { CategoryProductRelation as r join Category as c on {r.source}= {c.pk} } where {c.code}='shoes' }}) "
```

Comment: Thanks!! it works! another question..how can i see this search restriction via backoffice?

Comment: You can navigate to System > Personalization in admininstration cockpit (default view) of backoffice.

Comment: Hey! I found this query pretty close to my needs. My VariantProducts have a "BaseProduct" field. I need to make a restriction by category like this, but searching in my baseproduct field!